# OneDrive Show sync status on file icons

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

Since the last update my OneDrive doesn't show the sync status superimposed on the file icons anymore. The status is now in a seperate column in Windows Explorer. How do I revert this? I kinda liked the old style and it feels weird with a seperate column.

I know that this corresponds to the files on demand setting but in the newest OneDrive client version 23.114.0530.0001 there is no files on demand setting anymore. I can just choose to download always everything (which is most likely the same at the end) but my sync status stays in the seperate column.

I even checked `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\` and all the 6 entries are present and the path is valid. And I verified that `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive` has `FilesOnDemandEnabled` with value `0`.

Sadly, nothing does help. Is there any other trick I did not think of?

Comment: Try in Explorer *View > Options > View* at the end to check "Always show availability status".